# Container Blobs with metadata

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

We have created a storage account for images and uploaded many images with the metadata property set. (as given below)

```
 public async Task<bool> UploadFileToBlob(CustomFile file)
    {
        // Get Blob Container
        CloudBlobContainer container = BlobUtilities.GetBlobClient.GetContainerReference("documents");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();

        // Get reference to blob (binary content)
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);

        // set its properties
        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file.FileMime;
        blockBlob.Metadata["tag"] = "computer";
        :
        :
}
```

There could be multiple images could have uploaded with the same tag name as a meta data property.

Now, I need to just get the list of images from the blob container which are mapped with the same tag name (I saw samples to download all the blobcontent but I want to specifically get the filtered list with the specific tag name which was set in the meta data of the uploaded file)

Thanks

Comment: I do believe there is now some Azure Search indexing service or some such which runs over blob metadata. Came across it the other day. Give it a search.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported to filter metadata in a server query. You would need to [list all the blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_ListBlobs_System_String_System_Boolean_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobListingDetails_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_) with [BlobListingDetails.Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.bloblistingdetails?view=azure-dotnet), and filter the tag name on client side.

Answer (score 0):

> There could be multiple images could have uploaded with the same tag name as a meta data property. Now, I need to just get the list of images from the blob container which are mapped with the same tag name.

As Zhaoxing Lu answered that there is no build-in features for you to achieve your purpose. Per my understanding, you could include path information in your blob names, you could create a virtual directory structure based on the `tag` category as follows:

```
https://{accountname}.blob.core.windows.net/{container-name}/{tag01}/photo1.jpg
https://{accountname}.blob.core.windows.net/{container-name}/{tag01}/photo2.jpg
https://{accountname}.blob.core.windows.net/{container-name}/{tag02}/photo3.jpg
```

Then, you could leverage [ListBlobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_ListBlobs_System_String_System_Boolean_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobListingDetails_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_) and specify the `prefix` parameter as follows to retrieve your blobs:

```
var blockBlobs = container.ListBlobs(prefix: "tag01").OfType<CloudBlockBlob>();
```